# Gamma and Pochhammer simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I want to perform some simplification on `Gamma` function and `Pochhammer` symbols. For example,

```
Gamma[a+m]-> Pochhammer[a,m] Gamma[a]
```

where a could be any complex number and m is integer. Similar relations for Pochammer symbols like,

```
Pochhammer[a+n,m]-> Pochhammer[a,n+m]/Pochhammer[a,n]
```

where m,n are integers and a is c-number. I want to define these rules first and then apply these to calculations where Gamma and Pochhammer appears (their argument may contain any combination of c-numbers and may or may not contain integers (Gamma[c1+c2+m+n] or Gamma[a2+n] or Gamma[b1] for example)).

Comment: `Pochhammer[a + n, m] /. 
 Pochhammer[a_ + n_, m_] -> Pochhammer[a, n + m]/Pochhammer[a, n]` try it.

Comment: The following works : `Pochhammer[a + n, m] /. Pochhammer[a_ + n, m] -> Pochhammer[a, n + m]/Pochhammer[a, n]`